# TriggerIO 1.4 breaks Android <select> box functionality?

Tags: android, trigger.io

I'm writing an app with TriggerIO for Android 3.2 and testing on the Motorola Xyboard (Xoom 2) tablet. After migrating to 1.4, my HTML select boxes generate an error when trying to change values, and the application is force closed. To test, I created a vanilla static HTML select box with two test options and it still generates an error when I tap to change values. When rebuilding with 1.3 this error disappears.

Edit: Thought I should add - migration was a bit tricky, using the Migrate tool in Trigger Toolkit said it was successful, but returned me to my app which was still set to use 1.3 and prompted me to migrate again. After a few of these loops, I then used the command line tool, which again said was successful, but my app was still set to 1.3 and asking me to migrate. In the options tab within the Toolkit, there was only options for 1.3 platform. I ended up changing the platform version to 1.4 by editing the config.json file manually, which finally caused my app to rebuild with 1.4.

Comment: Oh man.  And you are not using jQuery, zepto, underscore, or jQuery mobile?

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.7.2 - but for the test case I didn't attach any event handlers

Comment: Can you email support@trigger.io with a snippet showing the problem and we'll try to recreate and fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest 1.4 platform (1.4.3) fixes this issue.